# Generating Cartesian products in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples, cartesian-product

I am trying to generate all possible combinations of n numbers. For example if n = 3 I would want the following combinations:

```
(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2)... (0,0,9), (0,1,0)... (9,9,9).
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180196/generating-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-in-a-triplet) describes how to do so for n = 3:

```
[(a,b,c) | m <- [0..9], a <- [0..m], b <- [0..m], c <- [0..m] ]
```

Or to avoid duplicates (i.e. multiple copies of the same n-uple):

```
let l = 9; in [(a,b,c) | m <- [0..3*l],
                         a <- [0..l], b <- [0..l], c <- [0..l],
                         a + b + c == m ]
```

However following the same pattern would become very silly very quickly for `n > 3`. Say I wanted to find all of the combinations: `(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)`, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Ideally I'd rather not use a built in funtion as I am trying to learn Haskell and I would rather take the time to understand a peice of code than just use a package written by someone else. A tuple is not required, a list would also work.

Comment: Just write a recursive function. Given the combinations for `n-1` choices, generate those for `n` choices. You'll want to output a list, not a fixed-length tuple.

Comment: If after you solve this you want to exploit library functions anyway, know that `replicateM n [1..100]` does the job. It's a non-trivial exercise to realize why, though -- so leave that for when you are more familiar with Haskell.

Comment: `sequence $ replicate 3 [0..9]` will generate the cross product as a list, not a tuple but easy to generalize

Comment: Generate all combinations of numbers... for e.g. 3 digits that'd be `000`, `001`, `002`... `009`, `010`, `011`... `999`... Am I missing something, or isn't this the mathematical concept known as **counting**?

Comment: The two code samples you provide seem to do different things, neither of which is what you describe in the first paragraph. Looking at the linked post it makes a bit more sense, but even so its not clear.

Comment: Are tuples required or will a list work?

Comment: Define "duplicate". Do you mean the same n-uple appearing multiple times, or duplicates *inside* an n-uple? Also does ordering of the elements of a tuple count?

Comment: @karakfa Thanks, that is simple and works perfectly!

Comment: Why nobody mentioned that this question has absolutely nothing to do with combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are all the combinations of three digits? Let's write a few out manually.

```
000, 001, 002 ... 009, 010, 011 ... 099, 100, 101 ... 998, 999
```

We ended up simply *counting*! We enumerated all the numbers between 0 and 999. For an arbitrary number of digits this generalises straightforwardly: the upper limit is `10^n` (exclusive), where `n` is the number of digits.

Numbers are designed this way on purpose. It would be jolly strange if there was a possible combination of three digits which wasn't a valid number, or if there was a number below 1000 which couldn't be expressed by combining three digits!

This suggests a simple plan to me, which just involves arithmetic and doesn't require a deep understanding of Haskell*:

1. Generate a list of numbers between 0 and `10^n`
2. Turn each number into a list of digits.

Step 2 is the fun part. To extract the digits (in base 10) of a three-digit number, [you do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell):

1. Take the quotient and remainder of your number with respect to 100. The quotient is the first digit of the number.
2. Take the remainder from step 1 and take its quotient and remainder with respect to 10. The quotient is the second digit.
3. The remainder from step 2 was the third digit. This is the same as taking the quotient with respect to 1.

For an *n*-digit number, we take the quotient `n` times, starting with `10^(n-1)` and ending with `1`. Each time, we use the remainder from the last step as the input to the next step. This suggests that our function to turn a number into a list of digits should be implemented as a fold: we'll thread the remainder through the operation and build a list as we go. (I'll leave it to you to figure out how this algorithm changes if you're not in base 10!)

---

Now let's implement that idea. We want calculate a specified number of digits, zero-padding when necessary, of a given number. What should the type of `digits` be?

```
digits :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

Hmm, it takes in a number of digits and an integer, and produces a list of integers representing the digits of the input integer. The list will contain single-digit integers, each one of which will be one digit of the input number.

```
digits numberOfDigits theNumber = reverse $ fst $ foldr step ([], theNumber) powersOfTen
    where step exponent (digits, remainder) =
              let (digit, newRemainder) = remainder `divMod` exponent
              in (digit : digits, newRemainder)
          powersOfTen = [10^n | n <- [0..(numberOfDigits-1)]]
```

What's striking to me is that this code looks quite similar to my English description of the arithmetic we wanted to perform. We generate a powers-of-ten table by exponentiating numbers from 0 upwards. Then we fold that table back up; at each step we put the quotient on the list of digits and send the remainder to the next step. We have to `reverse` the output list at the end because of the right-to-left way it got built.

By the way, the pattern of generating a list, transforming it, and then folding it back up is an idiomatic thing to do in Haskell. It's even got its own high-falutin' mathsy name, *hylomorphism*. [GHC knows about this pattern too](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html#idp46686526200096) and can compile it into a tight loop, optimising away the very existence of the list you're working with.

Let's test it!

```
ghci> digits 3 123
[1, 2, 3]
ghci> digits 5 10101
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
ghci> digits 6 99
[0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9]
```

It works like a charm! (Well, it misbehaves when `numberOfDigits` is too small for `theNumber`, but never mind about that.) Now we just have to generate a counting list of numbers on which to use `digits`.

```
combinationsOfDigits :: Int -> [[Int]]
combinationsOfDigits numberOfDigits = map (digits numberOfDigits) [0..(10^numberOfDigits)-1]
```

... and we've finished!

```
ghci> combinationsOfDigits 2
[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],[0,8],[0,9],[1,0],[1,1] ... [9,7],[9,8],[9,9]]
```

<sub>* For a version which *does* require a deep understanding of Haskell, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35108876/1523776).</sub>

Comment: This was an incredible post! Haskell is continuously blowing my mind! Do you have any tutorials that you would reccomend? As you noted this answer is easier to follow than your second one and while I think I can understand this one, I barely touch the surface of the other one. It is very intimidating! However it was very cool to see how your solution tied so nicely into the Standard Library. If I could accept both asnwers I would!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help. Tutorial-wise, you may have read it already but [_Learn You A Haskell_](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) remains one of the best programming books I've ever read. It's funny and approachable and it explains the more advanced topics very well. By the way, if there's anything you don't understand about the other answer I'll be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 9):

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35108514/1523776) gave an arithmetic algorithm to enumerate all the combinations of digits. Here's an alternative solution which arises by generalising your example. It works for non-numbers, too, because it only uses the structure of lists.

First off, let's remind ourselves of how you might use a list comprehension for three-digit combinations.

```
threeDigitCombinations = [[x, y, z] | x <- [0..9], y <- [0..9], z <- [0..9]]
```

What's going on here? The list comprehension corresponds to nested loops. `z` counts from 0 to 9, then `y` goes up to 1 and `z` starts counting from 0 again. `x` ticks the slowest. As you note, the shape of the list comprehension changes (albeit in a uniform way) when you want a different number of digits. We're going to exploit that uniformity.

```
twoDigitCombinations = [[x, y] | x <- [0..9], y <- [0..9]]
```

We want to abstract over the number of variables in the list comprehension (equivalently, the nested-ness of the loop). Let's start playing around with it. First, I'm going to rewrite these list comprehensions as their equivalent *monad comprehensions*.

```
threeDigitCombinations = do
    x <- [0..9]
    y <- [0..9]
    z <- [0..9]
    return [x, y, z]
twoDigitCombinations = do
    x <- [0..9]
    y <- [0..9]
    return [x, y]
```

Interesting. It looks like `threeDigitCombinations` is roughly the same monadic action as `twoDigitCombinations`, but with an extra statement. Rewriting again...

```
zeroDigitCombinations = [[]]  -- equivalently, `return []`
oneDigitCombinations = do
    z <- [0..9]
    empty <- zeroDigitCombinations
    return (z : empty)
twoDigitCombinations = do
    y <- [0..9]
    z <- oneDigitCombinations
    return (y : z)
threeDigitCombinations = do
    x <- [0..9]
    yz <- twoDigitCombinations
    return (x : yz)
```

It should be clear now what we need to parameterise:

```
combinationsOfDigits 0 = return []
combinationsOfDigits n = do
    x <- [0..9]
    xs <- combinationsOfDigits (n - 1)
    return (x : xs)

ghci> combinationsOfDigits' 2
[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],[0,8],[0,9],[1,0],[1,1] ... [9,8],[9,9]]
```

---

It works, but we're not done yet. I want to show you that this is an instance of a more general monadic pattern. First I'm going to change the implementation of `combinationsOfDigits` so that it folds up a list of constants.

```
combinationsOfDigits n = foldUpList $ replicate n [0..9]
    where foldUpList [] = return []
          foldUpList (xs : xss) = do
              x <- xs
              ys <- foldUpList xss
              return (x : ys)
```

Looking at the definiton of `foldUpList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`, we can see that it doesn't actually require the use of *lists* per se: it only uses the monad-y parts of lists. It could work on any monad, and indeed it does! It's in the standard library, and it's called [`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence). If you're confused by that, replace `m` with `[]` and you should see that those types mean the same thing.

```
combinationsOfDigits n = sequence $ replicate n [0..9]
```

Finally, noting that `sequence . replicate n` is the definition of [`replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM), we get it down to a very snappy one-liner.

```
combinationsOfDigits n = replicateM n [0..9]
```

To summarise, `replicateM n` gives the *n*-ary combinations of an input list. This works for any list, not just a list of numbers. Indeed, it works for any monad - though the "combinations" interpretation only makes sense when your monad represents choice.

This code is very terse indeed! So much so that I think it's not entirely obvious how it works, unlike the arithmetic version I showed you in my other answer. The list monad has always been one of the monads I find less intuitive, at least when you're using higher-order monad combinators and not `do`-notation.

On the other hand, it runs quite a lot faster than the number-crunching version. On my (high-spec) MacBook Pro, compiled with `-O2`, this version calculates the 5-digit combinations about 4 times faster than the version which crunches numbers. (If anyone can explain the reason for this I'm listening!)

[image: benchmark]

Comment: Is this as efficient as the first answer? It looks like it should be, although I'm not particularly well-versed in the optimization power of GHC.

Comment: Good question, to which I don't know the answer. I'll benchmark it when I have time later today and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
combos 1 list = map (\x -> [x]) list
combos n list = foldl (++) [] $ map (\x -> map (\y -> x:y) nxt) list
    where nxt = combos (n-1) list
```

In your case

```
combos 3 [0..9]
```