# List to List of List with all possible combination

Tags: list, haskell

First of all, I cannot remember the name of this repetition of list.

I have a list:

```
myList = [0, 1, 2]
```

I want to repeat list of list:

```
[[0,1,2],[1,2,0],...]
```

I know that I can do `permutations myList`
But it won't cover the repeated parts such as `[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,0],...]`

So, my questions are what is the name given for such kind of list.
It is not `permutations` and it definitely is not `combinations`

In logic, we call it `truth table`, I believe.

And is there a builtin function for that in haskell?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084867/haskell-generating-all-combinations-of-n-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> replicateM 3 [0,1,2]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

Note that basically, the length of the list of permitted values needs in no way be connected to the length of each list of choices.

Answer (score 2):

with list comprehension

```
x = [0,1,2]
[[a,b,c] | a<-x, b<-x, c<-x]                           

[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],
 [1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],
 [2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```